# Problems with accessing lists via reference

Tags: powershell

Running the following code

```
$list = @(1,2)
$hash = @{
    foo =  @{"Param1" = [REF]$list}
}

function foo([REF]$Param1){
    $TempList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($Entry in $Param1.Value) {
        $Entry++
        [void]$TempList.Add($Entry)
    }
    $Param1.Value = $TempList
}

foreach($Function in $Hash.keys) {
    & $Function @($Hash.$Function)
    #& foo -Param1 ([REF]$list)
}
$list
```

will give me the error message

"Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Param1'. Reference type is expected in argument."

If I swap the function call with the one that is commented out, the script works. What do I have to change in my definition of the hash "$hash" so that the parameterype is correct?

Background:
I want to use a config file to call arbitrary functions with arbitrary parameters. This works, but obviously doesn't allow me to process the output as I can't know beforehand what the function will return. So the function needs to manipulate the list in the main script directly. I could of course just make that list global, but I would rather not. Or maybe it would be the better solution?

Comment: Splatting does not work on expressions, and this `@()` is array subexpression not splatting operator. `foreach($DE in $Hash.GetEnumerator()) { $Params = $DE.Value; & $DE.Key @Params }`

Comment: Following up on @PetSerAl's comment. Here is the reference to the [Array Expression Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/8981/special-operators/27942/array-expression-operator) and [Splatting](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/5647/splatting)

Comment: Thanks guys! Was trying to use the brackets to get ps to evaluate $Hash.$Function before splatting it. Somehow totally overlooked that that will of course make it into an array. Bit of a d'oh moment :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @PetSerAl's comments, you were using the array expression operator or `@()` instead of the splatting operator or `@`.

Here is my version of the code using the splatting operator.

```
$list = @(1,2)
$hash = @{
    foo =  @{"Param1" = [REF]$list}
}

function foo([REF]$Param1){
    $TempList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach($Entry in $Param1.Value) {
        $Entry++
        [void]$TempList.Add($Entry)
    }
    $Param1.Value = $TempList
}

foreach($Function in $Hash.keys) {
    [HashTable] $params = $Hash.$Function
    & $Function @params
}
$list
```

Output

> ```
> 2 
> 3
> ```